# Computed column in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, sql-server-2016

I need to create a computed column for an existing column in a table.

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable 
    ALTER COLUMN MyComputedColumn INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS DATEDIFF(DD, GETDATE(), MyDateColumn)
```

It's throwing an error in the `DATEDIFF` function, doesn't like the `DD` parameter and throws error on `GETDATE()` too.

Any idea/suggestion will help. Thank you.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: And what are the errors that you're getting? Paste the text of the messages into your question.

Comment: It says incorrect syntax near '('. and the red underline error is in datediff, day, and getdate's  ()

Comment: That doesn't look right, you're not adding a column with that syntax - in most databases you can't use non-deterministic functions such as `getdate()` and `generated always` is not Sql Server syntax?

Comment: You cannot use ALTER COLUMN to make a computed column, you have to drop and then re-Add the column.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table?view=sql-server-ver15#to-change-an-existing-column-to-a-computed-column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change a calculated column, you must first DROP column and then redefine the column as calculated.

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable DROP COLUMN MyComputedColumn 
ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD MyComputedColumn AS DATEDIFF(DD, GETDATE(), MyDateColumn)
```